# How to update/replace an existing object/entity in Doctrine without using merge?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Currently I am working with `Doctrine 2` within a `Symfony 2.8` project. The online Data can be sync with mobile apps. When the online project receives data from the mobile apps, the received entities are de-serialized from JSON and `merged` into the online database. Using `$entityManger->merge($receivedEntity)` automatically ensures that new entities are **inserted** and existing entities are **updated**.

This works fine `EntityManager::merge` will no longer be supported in `Doctrine 3`.

To prepare for this I would like to handle the merging manually:

```
public function mergeEntity($receivedEntity, $class) {
   $repo = $this->em->getRepository($class);
   $existingEntity = $repo->findOneById($receivedEntity->getId());

   if (!$existingEntity) {
       // Insert NEW entity
       $this->em->persist($receivedEntity);
       $this->em->flush();
   } else {
       // Update EXISTING entity
       $existingEntity->setProperty1($receivedEntity->getProperty1());
       $existingEntity->setProperty2($receivedEntity->getProperty2());
       ...
       $existingEntity->setPropertyN($receivedEntity->getPropertyN());

       $this->em->persist($existingEntity);
       $this->em->flush();
   }
}
```

While this work, it is quite cumbersome and not very flexible. Every time the entity class changes, e.g. a property is added, removed or updated, the merge method would have to updated as well. Additionally the method only works for one specific class and every entity class would need its own merge method.

While reflections could be used to limit these problems it is still far more complex than the existing `EntityManager::merge`...

Isn't it possible somehow to replace an existing entity with a new "version"?

```
// Is something like this possible/available?
$this->em->replaceEntity($receivedEntity);
```

**In Short:** Is creating completely custom update/replace methods the correct way to update existing entities? Or are there any build in features (beside `merge`) which can be used to achieve this?

Comment: You can insert an extra layer where you can take date from user input (like in form fashion) and let the `PropertyAccessor` (or whatever) do this job for you. I think that's not a issue of doctrine (and its version) but a totally different issue about your code